# Deploy web app on a server but pointing to many database schemas

Tags: web-services, rest, tomcat, schema

I have a web service app that has an xml file with Oracle connection properties i.e. DEVFOOBAR schema.  I will create a war file of this and deploy to Tomcat on our test server - however we only have this one server but we want the ability to test the webservice against a few different schemas e.g.

- DEVFOOBAR
- TESTFOOBAR
- UATFOOBAR
- LIVETESTFOOBAR

***Initial thoughts...***

Ideally we don't want to be digging about and changing the XML files in the depoloyed app on the server. I think we want 4 webservices all pointing to their own db schemas, so I was wondering what I have to do in order to achieve this.

Is it something to do with web.xml file, but then again I'm confused because if you have 4 webservices all doing the exact same thing, (except pointing to different databases),  surely things would get confusing if a request comes in to the server for a particular url (e.g http:\testserver:8080\myresource) - how will Tomcat decide which web service should respond, and if they all respond that's just crazy!  It's safe to say I'm a little confused here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, as part of your build process, create 4 differently named WAR files, each with the relevant DB configuration for a particular schema.

Once deployed to Tomcat, each WAR will be accessed by http://testserver:8080/WAR_name, so you will not have the conflict you describe.